# SUM function not working for cells with formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

```
A           B
----------------------
TOTAL       =SUM(B3:B)
Entry1      =IF($A3="Entry1","20",IF($A3="Entry2","170", IF($A3="Entry3","10")))
Entry2      =IF($A4="Entry1","20",IF($A4="Entry2","170", IF($A4="Entry3","10")))
Entry3      =IF($A5="Entry1","20",IF($A5="Entry2","170", IF($A5="Entry3","10")))
```

The values in column B are properly displayed (respectively "20", "170" and "10"). But the `SUM` function in B2 returns 0... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unquote your numbers like this:

```
=IF($A3="Entry1",20,IF($A3="Entry2",170, IF($A3="Entry3",10)))
```

Otherwise it treats the numbers like text.